# Proof that this recursive sequence is Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing, cauchy-sequences

> **29.18** Let $f$ be differentialbe on $\mathbb{R}$ with $a = \sup \{|f'(x)|: x \in \mathbb{R} \}<1. $
>
> (a) Select $s_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and define $s_n = f(s_{n-1}$). Prove $(s_n)$ is a convergent sequence.
>
> Elementary Analysis by Kenneth Ross, 2nd edition p.240

All the proofs of convergence I've seen (not many) start out with "for an $\epsilon > 0$, pick $\dots$". However, to me it felt more natural to put that part at the end, since there was a lot of stuff to develop before I proved that such an $\epsilon$ would work. Is this bad?

I would also appreciate any comments in any of the following areas:

Is it bad to make the proof as conversational as I did?

Is it unorganized or unclear in any way?

Did I appeal too much to the reader's intuition?

Is there a way I could've cut down on the length using this method?

Is there a better method? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For me, it is better to pick that "something" at the end. If I see a proof that picks that "thing" in the very beginning, it does not seem natural to me and it is meaningless for me if I can not see where it comes from. This is my opinion.

Comment: @Ninja Okay thanks for the feedback!

Comment: At the bottom of the second page the chain of inequalities goes in a strange order, starting from upper left, moving right, and then going down to the next line as an equality.  This is not the usual way of writing these (at least in English).  Typically equality in a new line is associated with the thing as the right-most part of the previous line.

Comment: @Glitch Ah yes I see it does look confusing, I don't know what I was thinking there. I think I can fix it by replacing the first equal sign on the first line with $\iff$, and then write the same inequality as in the line above, except now with the summation notation. The $\iff$ is a little awkward though